# Hausdorff dimension of cartesian product

Tags: measure-theory

The problem statement is:
Show that if the Hausdorff dimension of $X$ is $d$ then the Hausdorff dimension of $X\times X$ is $2d$. I was tried to solve it by showing that $diam(A\times A)=\sqrt{2}diam(A)$ for some arbitrary set $A$ but I had no idea where to go from there. How do I continue this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Only the inequality 
$$\dim (X\times X)\geq 2\dim X$$
 is true. It has many generalizations. You will find a nice combinatorial proof in Marstrand *The dimension of cartesian product sets*, Proc. Cambridge Philos. Soc. 50 (1954) 198–202. Or one using Frostman's lemma in Mattila's book *Geometry of sets and measures in Euclidean spaces* Theorem 8.10.

To see that the inequality above may be strict look into Kaoru Hatano, *Notes on Hausdorff dimensions of Cartesian product sets* Hiroshima Math. J. 1 (1971) 17-25. It is proved there that for any numbers $0\leq\alpha\leq m$, $0\leq\beta\leq n$, $m$ and $n$ integers, and $d$ such that 
$$\alpha+\beta\leq d\leq\min\{m+\beta,\alpha+n\}$$
there exist subsets $E_1\subseteq\mathbb{R}^m$ and $E_2\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\dim E_1=\alpha$, $\dim E_2=\beta$ and 
$$\dim(E_1\times E_2)=d$$
so you may take $X=E_1=E_2$ for $m=n=1$, $\alpha=\beta={1\over 2}$ and $d={3\over 2}$.

See also [this](https://mathoverflow.net/a/189275/16678) answer and the discussion on page 89 in the book https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/fractals-in-probability-and-analysis/D8CBD4181FDC20C387E22939DA2F6168#fndtn-information  available at
https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~bishop/classes/math324.F15/book1Dec15.pdf