# Example of Hausdorff dimension of product not equal to sum

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

If $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and $B\subset\mathbb{R}^m$, then we have the Hausdorff dimension of the product $A\times B$ is greater than or equal to the sum of the Hausdorff dimensions of $A$ and $B$.

What is an example where the inequality is strict?

Comment: Your question has an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1682684). Another construction can be found in Falconer's _“The geometry of Fractal Sets”_ (theorem 5.11) where he gives the example of two Borel subsets $A$ and $B$ of the real line having H-dimension 0, but whose product $A\times B$ has a strictly positive dimension. (In general $\dim(A\times B)\geqslant\dim A + \dim B$ holds.)